# How to group the array string in to object by matching?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to group an array of strings into an object. how to do this? Is there any easier way to do this?

This is what I expect:

```
// I want to convert this:
var mandate = ["sender.state","sender.city", "sender.postalcode", 
  "receiver.state", "receiver.city", "receiver.postalcode"];

// To this:
var groups = {
 'group1' : ["sender.state","sender.city", "sender.postalcode"],
 'group2' : ["receiver.state", "receiver.city", "receiver.postalcode"]
}
```

Here is my try:

```
var groups = {
 'group1' : [],
 'group2' : []
}

var mandate = ["sender.state","sender.city", "sender.postalcode", "receiver.state", "receiver.city", "receiver.postalcode"];

for( let name in mandate ){
    if( mandate[name].indexOf('sender') ){
    groups.group1.push(mandate[name])
  }
  if( mandate[name].indexOf('receiver') ){
    groups.group1.push(mandate[name])
  }
}

console.log( groups );
```

Comment: Hi! It's not at all clear what you're asking, not least because you haven't told us what the starting point is, please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) But separately, this reads a bit like a coding request. Instead, please do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: You can use map in javascript

Comment: You can achieve this by doing something like:

`var groups = {
 'group1' : [],
 'group2' : []
}

var mandate = ["sender.state","sender.city", "sender.postalcode", "receiver.state", "receiver.city", "receiver.postalcode"];

for( let name of mandate ){
  console.log(typeof name);
    if( name.indexOf('sender') > -1){
     
    groups.group1.push(name)
  }
  if( name.indexOf('receiver') > -1){
    groups.group2.push(name)
  }
}

console.log( groups );`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mandate = ["sender.state","sender.city", "sender.postalcode", "receiver.state", "receiver.city", "receiver.postalcode"];
var groups = {};
var groupByType={};
mandate.forEach((res)=>{
  const type=res.split('.')[0];
  groupByType[type]=groupByType[type]||[];
  groupByType[type].push(res);
});
Object.entries(groupByType).forEach((res,i)=>{
 groups[`group${++i}`]=res[1];
});
console.log(groups);
```